Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac 1n \int_0 ^1 \frac {f(x) x^n}{1+x^n} dx =\ln 2 $

Let $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+ $ be a continuous function with $f(1)=1$ and let $$a_n=\int_0 ^1 \frac {f(x)}{1+x^n} dx , n\ge 1$$
Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac 1n \bigg( \int_0 ^1 f(x)dx -a_n \bigg) =\ln 2   $
My attempt :-
Subsituting $y=x^n$ gives $dy=nx^{n-1}dx$
Thus $\frac 1n \bigg( \int_0 ^1 f(x)dx -a_n \bigg)    $  becomes
$$\frac 1{n^2} \int_0 ^1 \frac {f(y^{\frac 1n})y^{\frac 1n} }{1+y} dy, n\ge 1$$
I would have got the required result if $n$ was in the numerator initially  and using $y^{\frac 1n} \rightarrow 1 , y>0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ with Dominated Convergence Theorem.
But it's not so . How may I proceed ?

I would try Taylor expanding $1 + x^n$ as a first approach… let me know if it works.

I would suggest doing it by the definition of sequences. We know that $f(x)$ is continuous on a compact set so it has a maximum and it is positive, so we can bound it, then just find $N=N(\epsilon), \forall \epsilon$.

Well it should be $n(\int_{0}^{1}f(x),dx-a_{n})$ otherwise you just have $\frac{0}{\infty}$ form which is not at all indeterminate and the limit is just $0$ as $\int_{0}^{1}f(x),dx-a_{n}$ is itself a bounded sequence. In this case, you'll end up with $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(y^{1/n})y^{1/n}}{1+y},dy\to\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+y},dy=\ln(2)$

The theorem as you state it is not correct.
Let $M= \max_{[0,1]} f(x)$, which exists because $f$ is continuous and the interval is closed. Then, $0\leq \int_0^1f(x)dx \leq M$. Next, since $0\leq \frac{1}{x^n+1}\leq 1$ on $[0,1]$, $0\leq a_n\leq M$ for every $n$.
Therefore, $|\int_0 ^1 f(x)dx -a_n| $ is always bounded above by $2M$, meaning the limit you provide must converge to zero.
If you can prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\bigg( \int_0 ^1 f(x)dx -a_n \bigg) =\ln 2   $, then that suggests the original question was a typo, with $n$ supposed to be multiplied not divided. It is also another way of proving the limit you give must be zero, because of the multiplication law for limits.

So if we assume that there is indeed a typo in the OP, then the term in front of the last integral above is $\frac{1}{n}\times n=1$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}\times\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n^2}$; accordingly, applying Lebesgue's DCT (the integrand being bounded by $|f|_{L^\infty(0,1)}$) yields $f(1)\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y}=\ln(2)$.

More precise than $|\dots|\le2M$: $$0\le\int_0 ^1 f(x)dx -a_n\le M.$$
